# how to get the version of addons installed by Package?

Tags: emacs, package, version

Using elisp, how can I get the version of a package installed by the Emacs package management tool - Package? There must be some way to do that, because the version information is given in *package* buffer created by `list-packages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun get-package-version (name)
  (when (member name package-activated-list)
    (package-desc-vers (cdr (assoc name package-alist)))))
```

Most package versions are stored as a list of `[major-version minor-version]`. Melpa packages that are built from GitHub use a time of form `[YYYYMMDD hhmm]` If you want a string from these lists, you can do something like:

```
(defun* package-version-string ((major minor))
  (format "%s.%s" major minor))

(package-version-string (get-package-version 'pep8))  ; => "1.2"
```

**Update**: To get packages that aren't installed, we can test membership of `package-archive-contents`, like so:

```
(defun get-not-installed-packages ()
  (remove-if (lambda (x) (assoc (car x) package-alist)) package-archive-contents))

(defun get-not-installed-package-version (name)
  (let ((pkg (assoc name (get-not-installed-packages))))
    (when pkg
      (package-desc-vers (cdr pkg)))))
```

Comment: thanks. do you know how to get the version for a package not installed?

Comment: Change that `when` to `unless`. From what I can tell, 'package-activated-list' contains all installed packages.

Comment: that won't work. `package-alist` also contains installed packages only.